# woocommerce add meta_key and meta_value for every customer

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a list of users, which are customers in the woocommerce database, I want to add a status meta field for every customers in the woocommerce except `(a@gmail.com,b@gmail.co,c@gmail.com)` and the meta_field to add is 'status' and default value is 'old'.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Adding a meta value to a default WordPress object is not that big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to add custom fields to user profile like this:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields' );

function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="user_status">Status</label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="user_status" id="user_status" >
                    <option value="old" <?php selected( 'old', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_status', true ) ); ?>>Old</option>
                    <option value="new" <?php selected( 'new', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_status', true ) ); ?>>New</option>
                    <option value="active" <?php selected( 'active', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_status', true ) ); ?>>Active</option>
                    <option value="deactive" <?php selected( 'deactive', get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_status', true ) ); ?>>Deactive</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

/*--- Save Profile -----*/
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    //typo fix
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_status', $_POST['user_status'] );
}

/*--- Show profile on users grid-----*/
function wp_custom_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['user_status'] = 'Status';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'wp_custom_modify_user_table' );

function wp_custom_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'user_status' :
            return ucwords(get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_status', true )) ?: 'Old';
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'wp_custom_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

### See Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Now open customer profile and update status accordenly.